# How should I test dependencies between methods using Moq?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I want to ensure that the method I am testing makes two calls to a mocked method using the same values for certain arguments. These values are generated inside the method being tested so are not known when the test is set up. In this case the method being tested is storing two related items in Redis, but this is not relevant to the question; it's the mocking that I'm asking about. I want to confirm that the way I've done it, which does work, is the best way to do it. Perhaps there is some other feature of Moq that I have missed that could let this be done in a better way.

This is what I have.

```
IRedisClient _redisClientMock = new Mock<IRedisClient>(MockBehavior.Strict);

string token = null;
DateTime expires = default(DateTime);
_redisClientMock
    .Setup(x => x.Set(KEY_PREFIX, It.IsAny<string>(), $"{TEST_ID},{TEST_NAME}", It.IsAny<DateTime>()))
    .Callback<string, string, string, DateTime?>((p, k, v, e) =>
    {
        token = k;
        expires = e.Value;
    });
_redisClientMock
    .Setup(x => x.Set(KEY_PREFIX, TEST_ID, It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<DateTime>()))
    .Callback<string, string, string, DateTime?>((p, k, v, e) =>
    {
        if (!v.Equals(token, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            throw new Exception($"RedisClient.Set expected value {token} but received {v}");
        if (!e.Value.Equals(expires))
            throw new Exception($"RedisClient.Set expected expires {expires} but received {e}");
    });
```

The fact that I've had to use exceptions in a callback seems a bit clunky, hence my wondering if there is a better way to verify this using mocking.

Here is an example of the code under test, a private method called by the method actually being tested.

```
string StoreClientDetailsInRedisAndReturnToken(string clientId, string clientName)
{
    string token = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
    string data = $"{clientId},{clientName}";
    DateTime expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(AdminSettings.Current.ExpiryDays);
    RedisClient.Set(KeyPrefix, token, data, expires);
    RedisClient.Set(KeyPrefix, clientId, token, expires);
    return token;
}
```

The token is included in an activation link sent out in an email, so we need to be able to retrieve the data using the token. The second Redis set is allowing us to also retrieve the token using the clientId, in order to confirm that the request is still pending. i.e. the link has not been clicked and processed and the Redis entries have not expired and been removed.

I'm sure that you will want to suggest other ways to write the code under test but writing this I can already picture other ways to do it. What I would really like to know from this question is whether or not Moq allows one to verify that two methods, related in some way, are both called in a particular sequence.

Comment: No, the way you've done it is not the best way, because if the second callback is never invoked (e.g. someone refactored the code) you will not know about it. If you post the code under test or a sample we can provide a suggestion perhaps.

Comment: The mock is declared with MockBehavior.Strict, which I believe will fail the test if the Set call is not made with the known prefix and ID, and some unknown value and expiry time. Thus, knowing the call must be made, the exceptions will catch the case of unexpected values. Am I wrong on that? Nevertheless it is ugly and I would like to know if there is an alternative using mocking. I will however include an example of the code under test in my question.

Comment: Your understanding of mock behaviour is not correct, `MockBehaviour.Strict` will throw an exception if something DOES call a method that was never `.Setup()` but not throw if nothing calls a method: https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart

Comment: @zaitsman Responding to your comment about Moq using a list - the comment will disappear once I delete my answer. But thanks! Learned something new.

Comment: Good to know about the Strict behavior. I previously thought it caught both cases where a call was Setup but not made and where a call that had not been Setup was made on the mocked interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how i would test this method.
It is all fairly straightforward and asserts on all the behaviours you have specified in your code.

```
[TestMethod]
public void StoreClientDetailsInRedisAndReturnToken_SetsTwoValuesInRedis_ReturnsGuid()
{
  var data = new List<dynamic>()
  var redis = new Mock<IRedisClient>();
  redis.Setup(x => x.Set(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<DateTime>()).Callback((string kp, string token, string data, DateTime exp) => data.Add(new {KeyPrefix = kp, Key = token, Data = data, Expiry = exp);
  var target = new MyClass(redis.Object);

  var result = target.StoreClientDetailsInRedisAndReturnToken("funny", "banana");

  new Guid(result); // do nothing, will throw if result is not parseable as Guid

  Assert.AreEqual(2, data.Count())
  Assert.AreEqual(KeyPrefix, data.FirstOrDefault().KeyPrefix);
  Assert.AreEqual(result, data.FirstOrDefault().Key);
  Assert.AreEqual("funny,banana", data.FirstOrDefault().Data);
  // here if you have enterprise edition of visual studio you can use microsoft fakes to actually test it, or otherwise
  Assert.IsTrue(((DateTime)data.FirstOrDefault().Expiry) > DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(AdminSettings.Current.ExpiryDays).AddMinutes(-1));

  Assert.AreEqual(KeyPrefix, data.LastOrDefault().KeyPrefix);
  Assert.AreEqual("funny", data.LastOrDefault().Key);
  Assert.AreEqual(result, data.LastOrDefault().Data);
  Assert.IsTrue(((DateTime)data.LastOrDefault().Expiry) > DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(AdminSettings.Current.ExpiryDays).AddMinutes(-1));
}
```

Comment: That's a nice idea, using a single Setup and Callback with a list to enable asserting on the values actually passed to Redis. Much cleaner than my original clunky exception based idea. I have VS professional so not familiar with Microsoft fakes; I'll read up on that. It had crossed my mind to declare an embedded class in my test class that does a minimal implementation of IRedisClient implementing only Set and Get so I could assert on the values stored; but your example is better, less possibility of introducing errors in the test.